# Hanging JDBC query with Impala

Tags: jdbc, impala, jethro

I am having a weird issue.   I am building an automated testing A/B tool in order compare *Impala* to other sources.  I have 100 queries I am trying to run, that run fine through other sources and within *Impala* through Hue.  I try to run certain queries into *Impala* from Java and it hangs.  I run same text in *Hue* and it works.  I figure it’s a non-printable character and remove all of them before issuing the query. Still hangs.  No exception bubbles up, sits there for an hour.  No evidence of query within *Cloudera Manager* I am at a loss.  This is for SQL A/B testing.  I have *Jethro* running consistently in 1-2 second range on almost all queries we tested.  I can't document comparison to Impala across 100 queries until I get over this hump. I tried setting *Simba JDBC* logging through connection string and that did nothing.

Any thoughts on next steps for debugging the issue? Believe it or not, I am locked down corporate machine and do not have HEX or ASCII char view of my query.

Comment: can you contact Simba support to get help with the logging issue, as if you can get that resolved you should be able to get a bit more insight

Comment: That is a good idea.   However, the Simba driver is provided by Cloudera.   I am looking toward internal support contracts...large bureaucracy.  Thanks!